# MySQL entity framework throwing exception when trying to add

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, entity-framework

I have tried to create a project that implements the MySQL entity framework. I have added the EntityFramework, MySql.Data, and MySQL.Data.Entities NuGet packages. I also have the mysql-connector-net-6.7.4 installed. I have tried deleting and removing all of these things, but I still get the error below. I have added it as a server in the project and have been able to hit the db and pull down the test_table. I have used the MySQL connection and been able to connect to the db through visual studio. I keep getting this error though.

It fails on the last line of the code below `context.test_table.Add(cookie)`.

```
sql123456Entities context = new sql123456Entities();
test_table cookie = new test_table
{
    this_is_cool = "Yes it is",
    this_is_cooler = 32,
    but_is_it_the_fonz = "Yeah!"
};

context.test_table.Add(cookie);
```

Exception message (inner exception is null)

```
{"Could not load file or assembly 'MySql.Data, Version=6.6.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)":"MySql.Data, Version=6.6.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"}
```

Stack Trace:

```
  at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMarkHandle stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName, ObjectHandleOnStack type)
  at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName)
  at System.RuntimeType.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
  at System.Type.GetType(String typeName)
  at System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(DataRow providerRow)
  at System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(String providerInvariantName)
  at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.DefaultProviderFactoryResolver.GetService(Type type, Object key, Func`3 handleFailedLookup)
  at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.DefaultProviderFactoryResolver.GetService(Type type, Object key)
  at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.CachingDependencyResolver.<>c__DisplayClass1.<GetService>b__0(Tuple`2 k)
  at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
  at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.CachingDependencyResolver.GetService(Type type, Object key)
  at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.ResolverChain.<>c__DisplayClass3.<GetService>b__0(IDbDependencyResolver r)
  at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()
  at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
  at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.ResolverChain.GetService(Type type, Object key)
  at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.RootDependencyResolver.GetService(Type type, Object key)
  at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.ChangeConnectionString(String newConnectionString)
  at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection..ctor(String connectionString)
  at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.InitializeFromConnectionStringSetting(ConnectionStringSettings appConfigConnection)
  at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.TryInitializeFromAppConfig(String name, AppConfig config)
  at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.Initialize()
  at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.CreateObjectContextFromConnectionModel()
  at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
  at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.Initialize()
  at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)
  at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()
  at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext()
  at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.ActOnSet(Action action, EntityState newState, Object entity, String methodName)
  at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Add(Object entity)
  at System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1.Add(TEntity entity)
  at ConsoleApplication2.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\Users\recursor\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\CS3280\Final Project\IR\ConsoleApplication2\Program.cs:line 24
  at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
  at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
  at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
  at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
  at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
  at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
  at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
  at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Comment: What version of that assembly do you have, if any?

Comment: I have 6.7.4.0 in all assemblies as well as what connector versioned and pointing to. I don't know why it is asking for that specific version either.

Comment: db is MySQL 5.5.34 so I higher version should still work for it (it is asking for version 6.5.5). I just don't get why it is asking for this version and why the one I have provided isn't working. I also don't know how to give it the one that it wants because I got this one from the most recent NuGet package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there were errors in the app.config. Under runtime there were dependent assemblies with binding re-directs that were improper. I had to be running EF5 because that is the last version of EF that MySQL supports. So I had to change the EF binding to this:

```
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.0.0.0" newVersion="5.0.0.0" />
```